# Break out of iFrame that Uses a Buster

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a website and someone is using the below code to force my website not to break out of their iframe. I've tried every available frame breaker script to no avail. Any help would be great! Thanks Guys!

```
Buster: function () {

    var interval = setInterval(function () {

        if (Lbjs.IsClick) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        else if (Lbjs.Unload > 0) {
            Lbjs.Unload -= 2;
            window.top.location.replace("/cancelnavigation/");
            Lbjs.NavigationNotice();
        }
    }, 1);

    var clearDelay = (this.Countdown > 0) ? this.Countdown : 8;
    setTimeout(function () { clearInterval(interval); }, clearDelay * 1000);
},

NavigationNotice: function () {

    var navNotice = document.getElementById("navNotice");
    navNotice.innerHTML = "<span class=\"warning\" style=\"text-align:center;height:20px;width: 400px;padding: 10px;\"><b>Request Cancelled</b> - Navigation is disabled for 8 Seconds...</span>";

    if (navNotice.style.display == "none") {
        this.Fader.FadeIn(navNotice, 200, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                Lbjs.Fader.FadeOut(navNotice, 200, null);
            }, 1500);
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: Are you setting the X-Frame-Options header? If not, you should be.

Answer (score 0):

Check the referrer of the page, and simply send something else if the request comes from their server.

This has to be done using a server platform though, it can't be done using Javascript.

Comment: Id rather have my site take over their screen then showing a different page.

Comment: @GeorgeMilonas: Well, they have taken offensive measures to prevent that, so your remaining course of action is to deny them your information.